# Glue to hold together wooden frame and mirror

Tags: adhesive, mirror, frame

I need to glue wooden frame to back of a small mirror, it's not that heavy - everything together should be around 4kg (9lbs). I know that there are specific mirror adhesives but can I use Universal/All-Purpose glue instead and will it hold? I have [Bison Universal](https://www.bison.net/en/product.6310911) and [Pattex Multi-Purpose](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0048F3EZG) already lying around. Also, mirror will be placed above [Zone 2](https://www.lyco.co.uk/advice/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Bathroom-Zones.jpg) so only moisture there might be from occasional shower steam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual approach for mounting glass to wood is to mount it in a rabbit, using use some form of stays so the glass is effectively sitting in a groove. For a mirror that could just be pins/staples/points, as you would use when framing a picture behind glass. For clear glass you'd use trim that fills in the rabbeted-out space attractively.

Mirrors in particular are often surface-mounted using "mirror clips" that affix to the surface with screws; those could be used in the back of a frame too, if there's room to drive the screws.

You might get other advice on this in the Woodworking stack. It's closer to woodworking than to home renovation.

Comment: Yup, use wood glue to assemble the frame, then set the mirror in the rabbet/rebate (EN-us/EN-uk) and hold the mirror in with glazier's points.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as all-purpose glue, even if labeled as such.

Wood and glass will expand at different rates depending on the humidity and temperature of the room, and this will break the bond between them. You need a glue that stays flexible under a wide range of temperatures and humidity conditions. I suggest a silicone-based glue, but there are other alternatives. Just look for "stays flexible".

Answer (score 0):

If you use an adhesive, you **need** to buy something specific to mirrors. Even then, there’s a chance of the adhesive pattern ghosting through. Suggest you cover the back in adhesive and use a v-groove trowel to make a symmetrical pattern.

It’s a much better idea to ‘clamp’ the mirror in the frame, as described by @keshlam.